# How to compare one object in a list to every other object in that list

Tags: python

So, for example, say I have a list like

`List1 = [5, 6, 7, 1, 40]`

And I want the solution to return true only if the value in the list that we’re looking at is 5 times large than every other member of the list. So if we’re looking at the first item, 5, the solution should return false (even though it is 5 times bigger than 1 it is not compared to the other members) and should return true when looking at the last member, 40. In python I wrote something like:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(list1)):
        if i >= (j*5):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

But I don’t think this is a great solution. I know this shouldn’t be so hard but I’m going through some health issues that’s making this hard for me. Any thoughts or help would be appreciated!

Comment: "if the value in the list that we’re looking at" - perhaps it would be reasonable to pass a "looked" value as param to a function - all the more you re trying to `return` at first pass

Comment: Your code you posted doesn't even check `List1` values and do something else (only checks indexes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing i and j instead of comparing the list values and you are  returning true before comparing your list1[i] value with all other list1[j] values.
Check the condition for all the j values, and use count to check if the value is greater than all other values.

```
count = 0
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(list1)):
        if (list1[i] >= (list1[j]*5)):
            count = count + 1
    if(count == len(list1) - 1):
            return True
return False
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you a list of True/False value for each element of `List1` where your condition is satisfied.

```
[all(List1[i] > List1[j] * 5 for j in range(len(List1)) if i != j)
 for i in range(len(List1))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def check(lst, value_index):
    return lst[value_index] >= 5 * max(q for e, q in enumerate(lst) if e != value_index)
```